# How to Display Product attributes on Product's Page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, tabs, attributes, product

I'm using Hellowired theme of magento and I'm trying to display Product attributes on the product page but it is not at all visible except Product description. I want to display tabs like 'product description' in 5 or 6. Is there any way to easily do this without going into code? or if I really want to use coding, then how?

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento admin (Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes), ensure that the product attributes you want to display are set to 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end'.

Then you need to hope that your theme is programmed to display them all. If it isn't then the only way is using code.

To use code, you will need to edit your theme's file:

app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

If you have never coded a Magento theme before you may want to do some research into [Magento's theme structure](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/how-magento-builds-content), seek some tutorials on 'local.xml' and if you want to understand what is really going on then work through [every line of code in Alan Storm's book 'No Frills Magento Layout'](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout).